# Can anyone help me to write codes for this in LaTeX?

Tags: youngtab

[image]

Please help me to write down the codes for the LaTeX platform.

I have written that

```
$t=
\begin{Young} 
$1$&$3$&$7$\cr
$4$&$5$\cr
$2$&$6$\cr
\end{Young}$
```

but it is not working!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! What have you tried so far? Please update your question with an MWE so we can help you better.

Comment: I have only written the codes for young tableaux..

Comment: @user454229 Anything you have tried will help us answer your question easier.

Comment: please, provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass`, with preamble needed to compile your code fragment and ended with `\end{dcocement}`

Comment: But what will be the codes?

Comment: @user454229: The code still is not a complete small document that others can compile. Please also describe what 'it does not work'  exactly means.

Comment: It is not coming in the same enviorment.

Comment: @user454229: As already asked in the comments to your previous question, please state if you have to use the `young` package or if you are free to choose a newer package like `youngtab` or `ytableau`.

Comment: @user454229: Instead of saying `thank you' only consider to accept one of the solutions below

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

When reading the [`youngtab` package document](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/math/youngtab.pdf#page=2), I see this in the beginning (page 2)

[image]

Maybe you get trolled, because **the `youngtab` package doesn't provide the `Young` environment!**

I continue reading and simply find a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}
\begin{document}
$t=\young(137,45,26).$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user454229 If any of the suggestion fulfill your requirement, then please accept that as the answer...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the `ytableau` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{centertableaux}
$
t=
\begin{ytableau}
  1 & 3 & 7 \\
  4 & 5     \\
  2 & 6
\end{ytableau}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]